# Query select all fields are not null

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table that I want to count number of fields which their field is not null. How I can return the result?

```
SELECT * FROM `fakelos2` WHERE fields are not Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of are use is, while to count rows for particular field, you use count function like below:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM fakelos2 
WHERE fields is not null
```

Now you have to count each and every field then you have to use case when then like below:

```
SELECT 
((CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+ (CASE WHEN field2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+ (CASE WHEN field3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
...
...
+ (CASE WHEN field10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM fakelos2
```